# @NameBinding causes java.lang.NullPointerException at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.RequestContextFilter$2.resetAttributes

Tags: jax-rs, servlet-filters

I'm trying to add a named ContainerRequestFilteron my JAX-RS project.
Firstly, I have created an annotation:

```
@NameBinding
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IsAuthenticated {}
```

Then, I have created the provider:

```
@PreMatching
@Provider
@IsAuthenticated
public class AuthenticationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("filter() on     ServerAuthenticationRequestFilter");
        Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.serverError();
        Response response = responseBuilder.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        requestContext.abortWith(response);
    }
}
```

Then, I'm using it on my JAX-RS method:

```
@GET
@Path("/trial")
@IsAuthenticated
public String trial() {
    return "Hello world";
}
```

Unfortunately, this is crashing with the following error:

> StandardWrapperValve[SpringApplication]: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   SpringApplication threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.RequestContextFilter$2.resetAttributes(RequestContextFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.RequestContextFilter.filter(RequestContextFilter.java:138)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:196)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:163)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:393)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:385)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:280)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

However, if I remove the following line from provider:

```
requestContext.abortWith(response);
```

then the crash disappears (although this is not working as expected, as the bad request is never returned).
I have added on web.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.trial.filters</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>com.trial.filters.AuthenticationRequestFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

What is going on? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The issue was being caused by @PreMatching, although I don't know why. But, I've removed that annotation and now it's working as expected.

Comment: Same problem for me here: I have a PreMatching filter aborting if a certain condition is not met. This causes the same behavior. Unfortunately removing the @PreMatching annotation is not an option for me. Any final fix for this?

Comment: Okay. This seems to have something ot do with priorities. Looks like the RequestContextFilter is invoked after your handler which causes the attributes of the active RequestContext not being set.